# Как вместо открытия уже существующего активити - пересоздать его?

Tags: android, backstack

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если пользователь заходит на активити А, а затем сворачивает его, то при открытии этого же активити (но уже через push-уведомление, а не историю приложений) - оно не пересоздается.

Вот так вот создаю уведомление:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.A);
intent.putExtra("DATA1", SOME DATA);
intent.putExtra("DATA2", "SOME DATA");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, 0);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.photo_icon)
        .setContentTitle(fullTitle)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: встречный вопрос - а зачем пересоздавать активити лишний раз?

Comment: @xkor, пользователь не завершил действие на уже созданном экране (и если он нажимает на уведомление, то не хочет его завершать). После уведомления выводятся совершенно другие данные, никак не связанные с предыдущим.

Comment: то есть вы хотите не пересоздать активити а открыть новое получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допишите в интент запуска активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.A);
intent.putExtra("DATA1", SOME DATA);
intent.putExtra("DATA2", "SOME DATA");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

Этим вы сообщите что он должен открыть новую активити в отдельной таске.

Comment: а если пользователь не свернул экран, но уже получил уведомление? В этом случае он не заменяется. Как по жесткому забить, что бы в текущем таске вызывался onDestroy и сразу создавался новый через onCreate?

Comment: Я сам отвечу на свой вопрос - есть флаг 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK', если кому пригодиться :)

Comment: PS Это помогает не полностью. Существует ли такая функция, которая выполняется при наличии этого флага?